# c++ recursion without if, or if related statements (switch, while, for, ?:, etc.)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, recursion, conditional-statements

I need to do a recursion exit condition without if, or if related. To be clear I can only use basic language. No functions, no functionpointers, nothing. I just want to call the main()-method recursively (bad style, I know) but there is no other way and i need to terminate the program deterministically, so no stackoverflow or anything in that direction although similarly hacky propositions are welcome. Any Ideas?

EDIT: 
These requirements are for a C++ JAPH. The reason I wanted to use recursion is to do a loop (which is not allowed either). Here are the specific requirements:

- only basic variable declarations
- only the methods/constructs sizeof(), getchar(), putchar(), printf()
- only setting variables as well as logic, arithmetic and boolean Operators
- no self declared methods
- only properly functioning code

Comment: Care to explain why? Please, I really need to know. And no, you can't call `main` in C++.

Comment: This appears to be an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Stating arbitrary requirements without stating what your actual problem is won't get you very far.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too narrow to be of general use.

Comment: Use a different language?  Maybe C.

Comment: One thing I know about recursion is that you always need a base case. How do you plan to exit this program when it is supposed to keep calling itself? Then you say you don't want `stackoverflows` LOL! You need to post your real question here rather than asking about your proposed solution to a probably simple question

Comment: @Smac89 You could use inheritance to model the base class. I cannot post an answer because the question is on hold, but I created an example online: http://ideone.com/NS4Hxh. You start with an abstract class List and two child classes Empty and Node. Node consists of a value (head) and a pointer to the remaining list (tail). List defines abstract methods, e.g. print, Empty implements it to print "[]" and Node implements it to print "[ head, tail->print ]". Although this is not very efficient and will quickly create memory leaks.

Comment: Recursion is practically ruled out with the restriction "no self declared methods".

Answer (score 3):

> I just want to call the main()-method recursively (bad style, I know)

Not just bad style, but explicitly disallowed by the Standard.  You can't call `main()`.

> To be clear I can only use basic language

I don't know what you mean by "basic language" -- but I'm guessing you don't mean the language named BASIC.

I also don't know why you would ever be constrained to implement recursion without using any conditionals like `if`, the only way I can think of is through template metaprogramming.

Example:

```
template <uint64_t N> uint64_t fact (); 

template <> uint64_t fact <1> ()
{
  return 1;
}

template <uint64_t N> uint64_t fact ()
{
  return N * fact <N-1>();
}

int main()
{
  uint64_t x = fact <3>();
  std::cout << x << "\n";
}
```

Comment: ... and I think one could make a fairly reasonable argument that template metaprogramming isn't really recursion... Sure, you can have some recursive template definitions, but by the time your program is compiled, it's all been resolved, so there's really nothing for your program to do with it...

Comment: @twalberg:  Yep, sure could.

Comment: @twalberg You could use inheritance to do the recursion. I created an example here: http://ideone.com/NS4Hxh, taken from Scala examples.

Comment: visual studio c++ allows and compiles a main-call in main, although i know its not allowed by the c++-standard

Comment: @singinWhale your car also allows you to drive it into a wall at 100mph. That a tool allows you to do something doesn't mean that doing it is a good idea.